# jQuery .post() is not triggering the success handler method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

**Situation:**

- I have a simple form and will call a `.post()`-call ([ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)) instead of the actual submit.
- The post works as such that it will post the request and receive a `200 (OK)` status with the expected string in the response body (as can be seen in the Net-View of FireBug).

**Question:**

- The anonymous function with the `alert()` is never executed. Why is that?

**Notes:**

- I have inserted an alert to indicate when the method fires
- fiddle-links for convenience below the code.

**The Code:**

Here is my form:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This was what I expected to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: "<span>jsFiddle test return msg</span>",
            delay: 1
        }, function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            $('form').append(data); 
            alert("done"); // <----- THIS NEVER FIRES
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/9NrL5/1/)

---

This does neither work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: "<span>jsFiddle test return msg</span>",
            delay: 1
        }, null, 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('form').append(data);
            alert("done"); // <----- THIS NEVER FIRES
        });
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9NrL5/2/)

---

This will trigger the alert but data will be empty.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: "<span>jsFiddle test return msg</span>",
            delay: 1,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('form').append(data); // <----- DATA IS UNDEFINED
                 alert("done");         // <----- THIS FIRES!
            }
        }, null, 'json');
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE 3](http://jsfiddle.net/9NrL5/3/)

Comment: Why are you sending HTML and expecting JSON ?

Comment: @adeneo This was the misconception that this parameter would specify the input type instead of the expected output type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting wrong datatype to json, server returns html type data. BTW, you don't need to specify it:

> dataType Type: String The type of data expected from the server.
>   Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

http://jsfiddle.net/9NrL5/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('/echo/html/', {
            html: "<span>jsFiddle test return msg</span>",
            delay: 1
        }, function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('form').append(data);
            alert("done");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I liked the deleted answer more since it didn't make me diff for the change. And explained what the error was. Could you please add what you did in your answer instead of in your comments next time?

Comment: Concerning datatype for $.post method: "Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html)."

Comment: Thank you! This is addition is very helpful.